# how to get same @XmlElement name in java class

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Trying to marshal one of the message and i need same name for different datatypes so that tag name remainssame. Following is the code but it is setting up for only one data type instead of all three.

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) 
public class Event { 

 @XmlElement(name="DataRows")
        private XData xData;
        @XmlElement(name="DataRows")
        private YData yData;
        @XmlElement(name="DataRows")
        private ZData zData;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)   
 public class Event {   
    @XmlElements(value = {@XmlElement(name="DataRows", type=XData.class),
                @XmlElement(name="DataRows", type=YData.class),
                @XmlElement(name ="DataRows",type=ZData.class)
        })
        private Object typeOfData;      
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an array or list with `@XmlElement(name="DataRows")`

You could do something like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public static class Event {

    @XmlTransient
    private XData xData;
    @XmlTransient
    private YData yData;
    @XmlTransient
    private ZData zData;

    @XmlElement(name="DataRows")
    public List<Object> getDataRows() {
        return Stream.of(xData, yData, zData).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share any example.

Comment: I tried to share an example based on the code you provided.Without more details of the other classes, XData, YData, ZData I can't be more specific